# Will a WebSQL DB sync with Chrome's app sync?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm building a packaged app for Chrome. I'm currently using WebSQL to store/retrieve data. Will data I input on one machine show up on another machine if I choose to sync apps in Chrome?

For example, on my desktop I open the app and add a record. If I open the app on my laptop will that record show up?

I'm not to the point where I can sync my app yet, so I can't test it myself. Has anybody done this before?

Comment: Outstanding question. I hope that someone has a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Chrome unfortunately (?) won't sync your WebSQL DB. You have to handle syncing through your server.
Just look at the choices Chrome gives you in the sync preferences:

- Preferences
- Bookmarks
- Extensions
- Autofill
- Themes
- Apps

Notice that not even Cookies are listed, let alone WebSQL databases. Syncing Databases would also be technically difficult, because they can get pretty big. The initial limit for WebSQL databases seems to be 5MB or something like that, but they can request more as needed. I think installed web apps can even request unlimited storage permissions.

Also there would be concurrency problems if two users edited the same data at the same time.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping that the db would be bundled with the app and sync that way.

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT: Just realized this is only in the trunk for google Chrome and not stable channel yet.  So it's hopefully coming but this feature is not available to general audiences yet :(

I was looking for similar functionality and I think I found it in Google's storage extension API - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/storage.html

> When using storage.sync, the stored data will automatically be synced to any Chrome browser that the user is logged into, provided the user has sync enabled.

I have yet to test it out, but if it works, it would definitely make sharing common data for simple extensions that much easier.