# Is LocalStorage synchronization for Chrome extensions already available?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, synchronization

I found [chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47327) titled *"Allow extensions/apps to sync their own settings"* that has status '**Fixed**'. It's from December 2011. So, does it work? If so, how does it work and where are the docs?

Last time [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213882/how-to-sync-chrome-extension-options) was asked in 2010 and then the answer was to use bookmarks hack. I think it's time to have an update on this topic.

**Update**: I just found [these docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/storage.html) for experimental `chrome.storage` API. Is this what I'm looking for? Do we have any new alternatives (other than bookmarks) till `chrome.storage` goes stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `chrome.experimental.storage` was introduced as an experimental API in Chrome 18.
- In Chrome 19, the API became restricted to the Dev channel.
- Since Chrome 20, the API is not experimental any more <sup>[Docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html)</sup>  <sup>| [Examples](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html#examples)</sup>.

To use the API, manifest version 2 is required. This is the minimum manifest file to get an extension to work in Chrome 20+:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is nothing in http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html about storage API :( How did you know about it? BTW, manifest version 1 works fine in Chrome 20 - check out this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html .

Comment: @KonradDzwinel Most of the content in my answer is not documented (yet). I've obtained the results by testing it. When an extension attempts to request the `"storage"` permission without manifest v2, this warning will be shown: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JIbbk.png ("'storage requires manifest version of at least 2").

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you are saying that manifest version 2 is required for extensions running in Chrome 20. And what you were actually saying is that manifest version 2 is required for storage API. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for help :)